# How to use multiple variables read from file with looping subprocess/popen

Tags: python, variables, subprocess, popen

I am using python to read 2 files from my linux os.  One contains a single entry/number 'DATE':

> ```
> 20111125
> ```

the other file contains many entries, 'TIME':

> ```
> 042844UTC
> 044601UTC
> ...
> 044601UTC
> ```

I am able to read the files to assign to proper variables.  I would like to then use the variables to create folder paths, move files etc... such as:

> ```
> $PATH/20111125/042844UTC
> $PATH/20111125/044601UTC
> $PATH/20111125/044601UTC
> ```

and so on.

Somehow this doesn't work with multiple variables passed at once:

```
import subprocess, sys, os, os.path
DATEFILE = open('/Astronomy/Sorted/2-Scratch/MAPninox-DATE.txt', "r")
TIMEFILE = open('/Astronomy/Sorted/2-Scratch/MAPninox-TIME.txt', "r")
for DATE in DATEFILE:
    print DATE,
for TIME in TIMEFILE:
    os.popen('mkdir -p /Astronomy/' + DATE + '/' TIME) # this line works for DATE only
    os.popen('mkdir -p /Astronomy/20111126/' + TIME) # this line works for TIME only
    subprocess.call(['mkdir', '-p', '/Astronomy/', DATE]), #THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have necessary permission to create a subdirectory of the root `/` filesystem? `/Abstronomy/...` is an absolute path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `os.makedirs` (which does the same thing as `mkdir -p`) instead of `subprocess` or `popen`:

```
import sys
import os
DATEFILE = open(os.path.join(r'/Astronomy', 'Sorted', '2-Scratch', 'MAPninox-DATE.txt'), "r")
TIMEFILE = open(os.path.join(r'/Astronomy', 'Sorted', '2-Scratch', 'MAPninox-TIME.txt'), "r")

for DATE in DATEFILE:
    print DATE,

for TIME in TIMEFILE:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(r'/Astronomy', DATE, TIME))

    astrDir = os.path.join(r'/Astronomy', '20111126', TIME)
    try
        os.makedirs(astrDir)
    except os.error:
        print "Dir %s already exists, moving on..." % astrDir
    # etc...
```

Then use [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) for any `cp`/`mv`/etc operations.

---

From the [`os` Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html):

> **`os.makedirs(path[, mode])`**
>   Recursive directory creation function. Like `mkdir()`, but makes all
>   intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.
>   Raises an error exception if the leaf directory already exists or
>   cannot be created. The default mode is 0777 (octal). On some systems,
>   mode is ignored. Where it is used, the current umask value is first
>   masked out.

Comment: This did the trick!  I will admit as a noobie, I tried to import os.makedirs but I guess it's already part of import os?  Thanks!

Comment: Np, happy to help.  Yea, in general you import just the module, then use module.function_name

Comment: for TIME in TIMEFILE:
 ScratchDir = os.path.join(r'/Astronomy', DATE, TIME)
 try:
  os.makedirs(ScratchDir)
 except os.error:
  print "Directory already exists, moving on..."

Comment: I have a follow on question.  It seems that when I use the variable it has some trailing \n or CR at the end.  Is there a way to strip that off?

Comment: @maphilli14 Sure, `myVariable.strip()` will do that.  [Python `stdtypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) has a ton of built-in functions that are super useful; memorize that page imo :).

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of errors in your code.

```
os.popen('mkdir -p /Astronomy/' + DATE + '/' TIME) # this line works for DATE only
```

This is a syntax error. I think you meant to have `'/' + TIME`, not `'/' TIME`. I'm not sure what you mean by "this line works for DATE only"?

```
subprocess.call(['mkdir', '-p', '/Astronomy/', DATE]), #THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
```

What command do you expect to call? I'm guessing from the rest of your code that you're trying to execute `mkdir -p /Astronomy/<<DATE>>`. That isn't what you've coded though. Each item in the list you pass to `subprocess.call` is a separate argument, so what you've written comes out as `mkdir -p /Astronomy <<DATE>>`. This will attempt to create **two** directories, a root-level directory `/Astronomy`, and another one in the current working directory named whatever `DATE` is.

If I'm correct about what you wanted to do, the corrected line would be:

```
subprocess.call(['mkdir', '-p', '/Astronomy/' + DATE])
```

chown's answer using `os.makedirs` (and using `os.path.join` to splice paths, rather than string +) is a better general approach, in my opinion. But this is why your current code isn't working, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I did mean to use '/' + TIME but it would only create the DATE subfolders and never the TIME ones.  the os.makedir worked. Thanks for your tips!